# $S$ is a minimal edge cut iff $G-S$ contains exactly two connected components

Tags: graph-theory, solution-verification

Let $G$ be a simple, undirected and connected graph and $S\subseteq E(G)$. Then $S$ is a minimal edge cut iff $G-S$ contains exactly two connected components.

$\Rightarrow$: Let $S$ be a minimal edge cut. So by removing edges in $S$, $G$ becomes disconnected. Let $uv$ be an edge in $S$. If we remove every edge in $S$ except $uv$, our grapgh is still connected. Each edge can have its endings in at most 2 connected components. So we know that after deleting $uv$ our graph becomes disconnected and that implies that $G-S$ has exactly 2 connected components.

$\Leftarrow$: Suppose $G-S$ has exactly 2 connected components. So if we connect a vertex in one part and a vertex in the other part by the edge in $S$ (that edge exists because $G$ is connected), our graph is connected and that is exactly the definition of a minimal edge cut, so $S$ is a minimal edge cut.

Is this everything written nicely? I must admit that am not 100% convinced if I made the right assumptions, so if it's good, does someone maybe have a tip or advice?

Comment: Your proof for the $\impliedby$ direction does not work, but that's partially because the $\impliedby$ direction is false. For example, in the complete graph on $\{1,2,3,4\}$, we can delete edges $\{12, 13, 14, 23\}$ and leave just two components, but it's not minimal, because we could also have deleted just $\{12,13,14\}$.